# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS ) issue

Tags: curl, cross-domain, cors, cdn

I am storing font (font-awsome) in Rackspace CDN and use it in my website. The font doesn't load and error message is:

```
    Font from origin 'http://some address.rackcdn.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.my domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know this is the issue with CORD, so I used rackspace API to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin for both the container and the file `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. 
Verifying by `curl` command:

```
   curl -I -X HEAD http://some addresss.rackcdn.com/production/assets/fontawesome-webfont-5019d8b3ed6173ce677c8fb2cfaf70c4.ttf
```

The result:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 07:20:04 GMT
    ETag: c4668ed2440df82d3fd2f8be9d31d07d
    X-Timestamp: 1410333603.37481
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Type: application/x-font-truetype
    X-Trans-Id: txbcf7f6de9f7848359081c-00540ffbd4dfw1
    Cache-Control: public, max-age=259176
    Expires: Sat, 13 Sep 2014 07:20:28 GMT
    Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 07:20:52 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
```

I also can download the font by entering the url to the address bar in browser. However I still can't use that font in my website, the previous error message is still there.

I also tried to test with javascript:

```
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'http://my file url);
    request.send(null)
```

The error message is

```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my file url. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It seem that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not enough for the CORS problem. What should I need to add more to the rackspace CDN header configuration/or my website  to use a font from Rackspace CDN ?

Thanks !